# Scala XML structure transformation issue

Tags: xml, scala, structure, transformation

Hello I have a problem in my Scala program.
I get next XML document

```
<mainTag>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
  <b>3</b>
</mainTag>
```

After conversion into JSON with net.liftweb.Xml mainTag is converted to JSON-Object with fields a, b, b. And Second b value is lost.

Could you help me with transforming XML to something like:

```
<mainTag>
  <a>1</a>
  <c>
     <b>2</b>
     <b>3</b>
  </c>
</mainTag>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the method which you have tried so far to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 2):

This solution provides required result:

```
val data = <mainTag>
               <a>1</a>
               <b>2</b>
               <b>3</b>
             </mainTag>
```

1)

```
val elem = <mainTag>
             {
               data.child.filter(_.label != "b") ++
               <c>{ data \ "b" }</c>
             }
           </mainTag>
```

2)

```
val elem = <mainTag>
             {
               val parts = data.child.partition(_.label != "b")
               parts._1 ++ <c>{ parts._2 }</c>
             }
           </mainTag>
```

Result:

```
val p = new scala.xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 2)
var res = p.format(elem)

println(res)
```